# asp.net MVC how to show chlid count of model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

i have a model named ProductGroup and i want to show count of child for any product group in view .

[image]

Comment: Post your code, not an image of it. And show what you have tried.

Comment: What is wrong with looping on ProductGroup list and doing `pg.Products.Count` ?

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty simple LINQ query:

```
var productChildCounts = context.ProductGroups
                .Include(pg => pg.Products)
                .Include(pg => pg.Attributes)
                .Select(pg => new
                {
                    pg.Title,
                    ProductCount = pg.Products.Count(),
                    AttributeCount = pg.Attributes.Count()
                });
```

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=513